# HTTP response being cached in Android client

Tags: java, android, json, apache, http

I have following situation:

1. Sending http post (post data contains json string) request to my remote server.
2. Getting http post response from my server in json: {"result":true}
3. Disconnecting all internet connections in my tablet.
4. Repeating post request described in step 1.
5. Getting the same cached "response" - {"result":true} which I didn't expected to get... I don't want that my http client would cache any data. I expect to get null or something like this.

How to prevent http client caching data?

My service handler looks like this:

```
public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method,
        List<NameValuePair> params, String requestAction) {
    try {      

        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
        HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

        // Checking http request method type
        if (method == POST) {
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            // adding post params
            if (params != null) {
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
            }
            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        }

        else if (method == GET) {
            // appending params to url
            if (params != null) {
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils
                        .format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
            }
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        }

        httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);


    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
       // Toast.makeText(Globals.getContext(), "check your connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }        
    return response;

}
```

Comment: Post responses are not meant to be cached. How did you conclude that the response was cached ?

Comment: I am checking logcat logs. When I disconnect internet and try to make request - I see previous response value (when internet still was working) instead of null or something like this.

Comment: ah ! I just noticed that `response` is a member variable. Why do you need a member variable to return this result. You're probably returning the same result on the 2nd try. Re-throw the exception that you catch instead and let the caller handle it. Let me know if that solves the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I solved my problem. One of the exceptions is throwing, so I was returning "old" response value because of it. Making return value null and putting additional return line above exception handlers solved my problem.

Comment: You're welcome. I've moved the answer from the comment section to the answers section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just noticed that `response` is a member variable. Why do you need a member variable to return this result. You're probably returning the same result on the 2nd try. Re-throw the exception that you catch instead and let the caller handle it.